# Calculate area between two lines Excel chart

Tags: microsoft-excel

how to calculate the green shaded area? if I calculate both areas and subtract, it gives me the subtract of both areas, instead of the sum of both areas, any ideas?

[image]

Comment: hi, please edit your question to include the formula you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a trivial challenge. Solving this with Excel charts requires an elaborate setup of helper cells and combinations of XY Scatter charts with Area charts.

Jon Peltier has a tutorial here https://peltiertech.com/fill-under-between-series-in-excel-chart/

I'm not sure if the intersections you are indicating will be possible with that technique, though.

Answer (score 0):

This question is more like a math question. Is the black dotted line at an angle of 45 degrees to the horizontal axis?

If yes, I would like to suggest you draw multiple auxiliary lines to create trapezoids and right triangles, which is convenient to calculate area. But please note it is not smart and it is not suitable for dynamic Scatter chart.

Assume that the 8 coordinate axes on the Scatter chart are as follows:

A1 (x1,y1), A2 (x2,y2), A3 (x3,y3), A4 (x4,y4), A5 (x5,y5), A6 (x6,y6), A7 (x7,y7), A8 (x8,y8).

[image]

The calculation formula is

=1/2*[(y8-y6)*(x8-x6)+(y6-y1)*(x6-x1)-(x2-x1)*(y2-y1)-(y2+y3-2*y1)*(x3-x2)-(y3+y4-2*y1)*(x4-x3)-(y4+y5-2*y1)*(x5-x4)-(y5+y6-2*y1)*(x6-x5)-(y8-y7)*(x8-x7)-(2*y8-y7-y6)*(x7-x6)]

Answer (score -1):

You simply have to add both green shaded areas - assuming that their sign is positive. The algorithm simply consists of adding up all differences of piecewise sections.

Each section is determined by two lines with two slopes. A section starts or ends when one or two line slopes change. It is not visible on your graph if the number of sections denoted above is really necessary for the calculation of the sections to the left.

If everything is based on points and coordinates and not lines and slopes the calculation for a single section is as follows:

From series a there are two points `(x1a, y1a)` and `(x2a, y2a)`. From series b there are two points `(x1b, y1b)` and `(x2b, y2b)`.

The area a from the line drawn between two points and the x-axis is simply

```
(x2a-x1a)*(y1a+y2a)/2
```

The other area b from the line drawn between two points and the x-axis is simply

```
(x2b-x1b)*(y1b+y2b)/2
```

The difference area with a positve sign is not `a-b` or `b-a` but `abs(a-b)`. Therefore the final term is `abs[ (x2a-x1a)*(y1a+y2a)/2 - (x2b-x1b)*(y1b+y2b)/2 ]`

After calculating the left green area by piecewise addition the whole area is the *sum* of both green areas because

`Sum from n=1 to m over all points + Sum from m+1 to n over all points = Sum from n=1 to n`

When looking at the example image of Emily the sections A2-A5 might qualify as a single section.

Comment: Please take a moment to learn how to answer questions. This is not the place for snide comments.

Comment: [... if I calculate both areas and subtract, it gives me the subtract of both areas, instead of the sum of both areas, any ideas?...] 
a1 + a2 gives the sum of both areas.
a1 - a2 gives the difference of both areas.
To get the sum use a1+a2.